# Creating a Commentary Section with React.js and MongoDB, how is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I started learning React.js about one week ago, and I'm still very unexperienced when it comes to this, I would like to have your help to discover how to create a commentary section with React and what's the better way to do it? Thanks all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm afraid this question is way too broad to be answered well on this site. You'll get more help if you try it yourself first, and then post any specific programming questions you have.

Comment: This is a rather broad question that cannot be answered with reasonable effort. Please do some research, try to code a commentary section, when you run into problems, ask a specific question, with code excerpts, error messages, observed and expected behavior, etc. Read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me direct you to a source that can help you discover *how to create a commentary section with React*

https://medium.com/@gsuppy/coding-an-interactive-comment-box-with-react-js-50d7d20587d8

I think you should attempt the task first.  When you come across some problems, then we can help dissect the issues together.